# How to scroll to the bottom of div after clicking on button x times?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, scroll

I'm making a panel which allows scrolling. Also, I have a button, I want to scroll the panel content to the bottom after clicking on the button 5 times *(5 x 20% of `scrollHeight` value)*.

I'm checking with the logging value, it's correct but indeed, the panel content has already scrolled to the bottom when clicking on the button 4th.

And the 5th, `value` is updated but the panel content won't scroll anymore.

```js
$('button').on('click', function () {
  var $panel = $('.panel');
  var scrollHeight = $panel.prop('scrollHeight');
  var value = $panel.scrollTop() + scrollHeight * 0.2;
  
  console.log(scrollHeight + ' - ' + value);
  
  $panel.animate({ scrollTop: value }, 500);
});
```

```css
.panel {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.panel div {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel">
  <div></div>
</div>

<button type="button">Scroll</button>
```

Comment: Try putting the addition in parentheses `var value = ($panel.scrollTop() + scrollHeight) * 0.2;`

Comment: If it's at the top, it would be 0, and 0*0.2 = 0.

Comment: @JoelHager Thanks! I just try it. But it's working wrong.

Comment: Console log the value on click

Comment: Also try this `var value = $panel.scrollTop() + (scrollHeight * 0.2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. It's math. :/ You actually want it into *6* segments if you want to click 5 times. The first state is the 1 out of the 5, so only 4 additional clicks gets to 5/5 through. I changed your scroll to `/6` and it takes 5 clicks.

```js
$('button').on('click', function () {
  var $panel = $('.panel');
  var scrollHeight = $panel.prop('scrollHeight');
  var value = $panel.scrollTop() + (scrollHeight / 6);
  
 
  
  $panel.animate({ scrollTop: value}, 500);
});
```

```css
.panel {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.panel div {
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel">
  <div></div>
</div>

<button type="button">Scroll</button>
```